# Globally overriding property access in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, decorator

I have the following classes presentation:

```
public class Item
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class DetailedItem : Item
{
   public Item item {get;set;}
   public override string Id{
      get{return this.item.Id}
   }
}
```

Like I showed in the Id property, I want to return the inner item properties when I access the properties from the DetailedItem.

Is there a generic way to do it without overriding each property?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to override the properties in order to make them `readonly` from the derived class?

Comment: This looks more like an architectural problem than a C# problem as such. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Have to agree with @SBI - this does seem a strange pattern with the derived class both inheriting from and containing a member of the base class.

Comment: There *is* a way, using `DynamicObject` and reflection... but I'm 100% positive that's not what you are looking for :-)

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to work this way?

`DetailedItem` *is* an `Item`, as described in the inheritance relationship, so why does it *hold* an `Item` and then overrides the other properties?

You can just create a `DetailedItem` class that inherits from *Item* and that adds new properties.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such a way. You have to grant access to the whole Item, or expose it's inner properties throught new properties. But it seems that there is something wrong with such a design. This smell is called "object envy".

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Item
{
   public string ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

ok so far...

```
public class DetailedItem //as an adapter or proxy object
{
    private Item item;
    public string ID { get { return item.ID; }}
    public string Name { get { return item.Name;}}

    public DetailedItem(Item item) { this.item = item; } //constructor
}
```

Comment: That is a good example of composition over inheritance, since `DetailedItem` (at last) doesn't _inherit_ from `Item`.

Comment: @heltonbiker exactly =) you could also make a common interface but for this demo its overkill i think

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an *inherited* class, like others have said. So your `DetailedItem`"is a" instead of "has a(n)" `Item`.

So you don't even need to repeat the properties from the base class in the derived class. You could do like this:

```
public class Item
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class DetailedItem : Item
{
   public String Details { get; set; } // just an example other property
}
```

Then you can call directly `DetailedItem.Id`, because it is already defined in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

[Roy Dictus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651188/roy-dictus) is correct. But if you come across any situation where you can't modify your structure and want to completly hide base implementation then use `new` keyword

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetailedItem : Item
    {
        public new string Id
        {
            get { return "newid"; }
        }
    }
```

> Remember, this should be a rare scenario and not common.